Desktop-app only opens terminal but not script
I tried to write a Desktop-App so i could start my pythonscript via the applications-tab. The Desktop-App exists but doesnt do anything somehow.
So i made my python-script executable (works perfectly fine if called directly or inside of an executable sh-file. My main problem is now, that i created desktop-apps by hand and with alacarte and neither of them worked. I even tried to execute the script indirectly through the sh-file.
Here's the one created by hand:
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=BullyBirds
Exec=/home/maxdu/0306/dartsapp.py
Terminal=true
Icon=/home/maxdu/0306/Bully Birds.png
Type=Application
Categories=Utility

The one created by alacarte is basically the same (exactly the same path) and the indirect one looks like this:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=BBApp2
Exec=/home/maxdu/0306/BBDarts.sh
Comment=
Terminal=true
Icon=/home/maxdu/0306/Bully Birds.png
Type=Application


with BBDarts.sh being:
#!/bin/sh
CWD="$(pwd)"
./dartsapp.py


The only thing i noticed is if i start the desktop-app with the terminal=true is, i can see the terminal open.
PS: As i mentioned both ./dartsapp.py and ./BBDarts.sh start the script perfectly fine.

what do you have in dartsapp.py? Maybe it has nothing to show. Did you run it manually in terminal to see if it gives any results?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

did you add #!/usr/bin/env python or #!/usr/bin/env python3 in first line in dartsapp.py? If you don't add it then ti doesn't know what program to use to run script. It doesn't care what extension has program - .py, .exe or even .png. If you don't add #!... then it may treat it as bash script and when it see line import .. then it may run system program import for screeenshots.

I did include #!usr/bin/python3 in the first line and when i call ./dartsapp.py it starts the same way it does with python3 dartsapp.py.

If i run ./BBDarts.sh, which does nothing more than call ./dartsapp.py it also works fine but as soon as i try to run it through my desktop-app the terminal opens and closes but nothing happens

if it open and close terminal then maybe it had to display some error message. Often problem can be /full/path/to/files if you use some files or own modules - because it may run code from different folder and may not find them. First step is to use module logging to write (in log file information what program is doing - what line of code is executed and what you have in variables. And it may need to use try/except to catch all errors and write in log file. And later you see what to fix. Other method is to use cd /full/path/to/folder/with/script in .sh before you run python script.

Thank you a lot for your tipps. The cd-line did it for me! didnt think that it would be necessary if the sh-file is in the same folder, but after adding it, everything works!

system may get line Exec=/home/maxdu/0306/BBDarts.sh and run it in your home folder. If you add print( os.getcwd() ) then you may what folder is used
